# How to remove a file from a pull request that I didn't modify

Tags: git, github

I'm not exactly sure how I got into this situation, but I am about to submit a pull-request to a repo in Github, but I'm finding that the pull-request includes a bunch of other commits (15) to another file unrelated to the branch.

The file I want to keep is called `tuition_benefit.json` and the file that I don't want is called `employees.json`. How can I remove all of the commits related to `employees.json` from my branch so that they aren't considered in the pull request?

I think that I must have been on the branch related to the `employees.json` file (`employees`) when I created the new branch (`benefits-query`) to make this new file `tuition_benefit.json`  instead of on `master`.

I only made 3 commits on this new branch, and the other 15 that are specified in the pull request are all related to the other file, which I never modified on this branch.

Comment: `git log --decorate --graph` will give you a better idea of what's going on in your branch.

Comment: @Schwern So, it looks like every unwanted commit was made before my 3, which makes sense. Is there a way to get rid of those commits on this branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *but I'm finding that the pull-request includes a bunch of other commits (15) to another file unrelated to the branch.*

This probably indicates you opened your branch on top of some other branch, or you have a locally modified `master` branch and branched from that.

Either way, your repository looks like this.

```
A - B - C [origin/master]
         \
          D - E - F [others]
                   \
                    G - H - I [yours]
```

You can see this with `git log --decorate --graph`.

`origin/master` is the `master` branch as it looks upstream. `yours` is the branch you want to submit. `others` represents what you branched `yours` from; that could be your locally modified `master` or another branch. Only commits `G - H - I` are relevant to your PR.

What you want is your work branched from `origin/master` like this.

```
          G - H - I [yours]
         /
A - B - C [origin/master]
         \
          D - E - F [others]
```

You can accomplish this with a rebase to replay `G - H - I` on top of `origin/master`. But a simple `git rebase origin/master` will not do. If you do that Git will replace everything between `yours` and `origin/master` including `D - E - F` from `others` accomplishing nothing. You need to tell it to ignore `D - E - F`. You do this with `git rebase --onto <from> <to>`.

```
git rebase --onto origin/master others yours
```

That will take all the commits starting at (but not including) `others` and up to (and including) `yours` and rewrite them onto `origin/master`. That's `G - H - I`. Then you'll have this.

```
          G1 - H1 - I1 [yours]
         /
A - B - C [origin/master]
         \
          D - E - F [others]
```

Note that it's `G1 - H1 - I1`. This is because `rebase` does not rewrite history, it creates new history. These are new commits. When you try to `git push` it will be rejected, because this isn't a simple update of `yours`. You have to `git push --force`.

In sum...

- `git fetch` (to get the latest `origin/master`).
- `git checkout yours`
- Examine `git log --decorate --graph` to determine where your work starts.
- `git rebase --onto origin/master <last commit that's not yours> yours`
- Test.
- `git push --force`

Comment: To verify that this worked (Test), do I need to go to the master branch? Or can I see the effects from my branch?

Comment: Never mind! It worked the way I wanted it to. Thanks!